# Is there a way to auto click all buttons on a page that say approve?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this site and i have to go down this list of about 800-5000 buttons a week clicking approve after each button the page refreshes and then i have to hit delete is there anyway i can automate this process? i want to click all the approve buttons at once and then after thats all done click all delete buttons :) Here is the HTML code for the buttons

Approve button`<td>
                                             <a href="index.php?menu=movie_links&amp;approve=2199" class="btn">Approve</a>
                                         </td>`

delete button`<td>
                                             <a href="index.php?menu=movie_links&amp;delete=2199" class="btn">Delete</a>
                                         </td>`

Thanks guys!

Picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1yDT.png
The top are ones i clicked and now need to be deleted the bottom are ones i need to approve then delete

Comment: Smells like a bad design......

Comment: you have no idea ha I didn't build it

Comment: Why not look in the script that handles the approval / deleting of all the posts? That is probably a lot simpler.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can use trigger() function on every approve button, and then on delete button

Comment: Do you have control over the source for this file? Or you just have to go through the page and keep clicking approve?

Comment: This seems to be circumventing the point of an approval process if you're just going to auto-approve everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have control over this page and it will be generated anyway, you can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) - it should be pretty easy to find all buttons that say "Approve" and go clicking them.